# What's the equivalent of "find -mmin" in HP-UX?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, hp-ux

I created a script to check XML file available in the
folder for more than four hours. If the XML is not processed for more than four hours then I need to send a mail
for that I used the below find command but the mmin+240 is not working. Is there is any option to used instead of mmin. Please help on this.

```
 find $OFILEPO/*.xml  -mmin+240  -exec ls -ltr {} + | wc -l
```

when I execute the above find command with mmin got the below error.

```
         **find: bad option -mmin
          0
         $ uname -a
          HP-UX**
```

I think mmin is AIX command. Please suggest for HP_UX
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Missing space after mmin?

Comment: It is showing bad option mmin in HP UX

Comment: Have you checked the man page of find?

Comment: yes it shows No manual entry for mmin

Comment: Try this: `find "$OFILEPO/" -name '*.xml'  -mmin +240 | wc -l`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the man page [hpux 10.20 - find (1)](http://ods.com.ua/win/eng/unix/usail/man/hpux/find.1.html), your implementation of `find` doesn't support the `-mmin` option.

The closest equivalent would be `-mtime`

> -mtime n                 True if the file has been modified in n days.

Similar questions ([Find files modified within one hour in HP-UX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441646/find-files-modified-within-one-hour-in-hp-ux), [how to find files modified in the last hour?](https://community.hpe.com/t5/System-Administration/how-to-find-files-modified-in-the-last-hour/td-p/3812226)) suggest creating a "reference" file with `touch -mt $time` and using `find -newer`.

Quoting the second link, you could do:

> Create a temp file using the 'touch' command, such that the modification time is one hour in the past. For example:
>
> ```
> # date +%m%d%H%m 06261006
> # touch -mt 06260906 /tmp/tdate
> # ll /tmp/tdate
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 26 09:06 /tmp/tdate
> ```
>
> Then run 'find' with the '-newer' switch, taking advantage of this
>   file:
>
> ```
> find /mnt -newer /tmp/tdate -type f -xdev -exec ll {} \;
> ```